# Why don't infinite sums make any sense?

Tags: infinite-product, infinitesimals

Using the infinite sum series, an infinite sum of (1/5)to the nth power, where n goes from zero to infinity, the general summation equation tells us that the answer is 5/4.  However, how is this possible, considering that each additional sum is smaller than the previous sum?  If you begin to do the math by hand, calculating and adding each sum individually, you get something like .249984...etc... where it appears that the number will extend infinitely to the right, adding decimal places and occasionally revising numbers later to the right of the decimal, but the additional sums should never be large enough to affect the initial answers in the decimal like the .2 part of the answer?  It seems very counterintuitive.

There seems to be a basic contradiction between the expected answer and the answer of the equation by a large margin of difference. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: It is just a logical definition: an infinite sum converges if the sequence of its partial sums converges finitely, and this limit is what we call the sum of the original series.

Comment: The first term of the sum you have calculated is $\frac{1}{5}$ so the infinite sum you want is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^n$$ which has value $\frac{1}{4}$ (note, the formula you used for the geometric series begins at $n=0$).

Comment: "but the additional sums should never be large enough to affect the initial answers in the decimal like the .2 part of the answer"  Why on earth do you think that? $\sum_0 (1/5^n) .... = 1.25$, $(1/5)^0 = 1$ so $\sum_1 (1/5^n) .... = .25$.  $1/5^1 = .2$ so $\sum_2 (1/5^n) .... = .05$.  $(1/5)^2 = .04$ so $\sum_3 (1/5^n) .... = .01$.  Does this still seem counterintuitive.  $(1/5)^3 = .008$ so $\sum_4 (1/5^n) .... = .002$...

Comment: Yep. You're using the formula for a geometric series, $\frac1{1-r}$. This series starts with the term $1$. You are omitting this in the hand-summed approximations.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Here's [a guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.

Comment: @Rob: Welcome to Math.SE. You might consider re-titling your question to something like "Seeming discrepancy with geometric sum formula." :)

Answer (score 12):

I suspect you're having an indexing problem:

- If we start at $n=0$, we're looking at the sum $$\left({1\over 5}\right)^0+\left({1\over5}\right)^1+\left({1\over 5}\right)^2+....$$ Here $a_0=1$, so the limit is $${a_0\over 1-r}={1\over {4\over 5}}={5\over 4}.$$
- If we start at $n=1$, we're looking at the *smaller by $1$* sum $$\left({1\over 5}\right)^1+\left({1\over5}\right)^2+\left({1\over 5}\right)^3+...$$ Here, $a_0={1\over 5}$, not $1$, so the limit is $${a_0\over 1-r}={{1\over 5}\over{4\over 5}}={1\over 4}.$$

Comment: Note that the difference between these values is $1$ - exactly what it should be (since the smaller sum is missing exactly one term, "$1$").

Comment: Ok, and thank you for the clarification.  So, the answer is a limit, and not a "solution" right?

Comment: @Rob I don't understand - what do you mean "not a solution"? The problem is that you forgot the first term when you started adding the series. The number you've computed - $0.24998$... - is an approximation of the value of the *second* series, which is $0.25$. When you plugged into the formula, you were computing the value of the *first* series, which is $1.25$. The only reason there's a discrepancy is because you forgot the first term.

Comment: Sorry, I misused the initial notation in my first question.  The above question (I'm not a mathematician) was meant to refer to the second series where n begins at 1.  That question is, does the summation series give a limit or not?  If it is a limit, then it makes sense to me.  If not, then the answer from the summation equation is not an actual sum when dealing with infinity, but an indication of the value that is approached (the limit), but never actually attained, right?  So, in the second series, wouldn't the actual sum always be slightly less than .25?

Comment: @Rob I think you're slightly confused about how infinite series work. In *both* series, the *partial* sums $a_0+a_1+...+a_n$ will of course be slightly less than the *infinite* sum $a_0+a_1+...$, which is **defined as** the limit of the partial sums. There's nothing special about the second series, here; in the first series, each of the partial sums will always be slightly less than $1.25$.

Comment: Thank you, this cleared it up for me.  The reason for the question is about precision.  If this is the case, then if I wanted to get a precise answer to a finite number decimal places (say, for example, 100 decimal places), would it be more precise to do the math by hand than to use the summation series equation?

Comment: @Rob No, the exact formula is still much faster. If you want an approximation of the infinite series which is accurate to some number of decimal places, then use the formula - and just chop off all but the first [howevermany] digits!

Comment: But the formula would say, for the second series, .25, whereas the math by hand, although slower, would be something like .24998...etc, right?

Comment: @Rob No. Eventually, the math by hand would get e.g. $.2499999...$ (several billion $9$s) and then a bunch more digits. It would get arbitrarily close to $.25$ - that's what "limit" means.

Comment: If the math by hand suggests that the answer is something like .249984...etc.., then how could that 4 ever get up to a 9 if we're only adding smaller sums?  Wouldn't the continuation just extend the decimals to the right, but not change the numbers? With each new decimal, it sill approaches .25 incrementally, but how would that change the numbers other than adding new decimal places?  So, the result by hand would seem to yield something like .249984...etc..., whereas the summation equation would yield .25?

Comment: @Rob You haven't added enough terms :). Add the first 12 terms of the series, and you'll get at least to $0.249999$. (Basically, every two terms the accuracy increases by at least one digit.)

Comment: I took the first 20 sums and got: .249999996379981176212 and the numbers are dividing at such a small amount that it doesn't appear that the "637" part is going to get touched again.  (Unless, this is my calculator doing weird things with rounding.)

Comment: @Rob It will indeed reach that far, surprisingly enough perhaps. By the way the exact value of the $n$th sum is given by $a_1*{(r^n-1)\over r-1}$. Note that the difference between this and $a_1*({1\over 1-4})$ is just $a_1r^n\over r-1$. Here, $r$ is $1\over 5$ and $a_1$ is ${1\over 5}$, so this is $1\over 4\cdot 5^n$. If you believe that this goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity, then you should believe that the formula is in fact correct.

Comment: Found the error. Thanks!  It's appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You are simply forgetting to include the first term, $\left(\dfrac{1}{5}\right)^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you try working in base 5 rather than base 10 then it will become more obvious.

It's kind of like how using 1/9 instead of 1/5 gives you 0.99999... = 1 which I hope you agree with.

Comment: That is fairly presumptuous: in fact most people *do not* agree with that statement. This is a logical conclusion if you think that a real number is defined by its decimal expansion. Moreover, the level of conceptual understanding demonstrated by the OP suggests that this could reasonably be the case.

Comment: @EricStucky: I don't know if you noticed, but the crux of the OP's trouble is the part that says *"...occasionally revising numbers later to the right of the decimal"*. I tried to show how to look at the same problem in a way that doesn't require that, thus reducing it to something that the OP would hopefully be comfortable with. If that isn't the case then I guess we'll see a comment to the contrary.